# Unable to push docker image to Nexus

Tags: java, docker, continuous-integration, nexus

I am running Nexus OSS version 3.29.2-02 and I am experiencing some weird behavior. I am building various images at a CI level (GitLab) and I am pushing them to a custom repository.

For the most part everything works OK and I have no issues tagging and pushing my produced images. Lately though, one of the projects that produces Docker images fails to push, with the following error:

```
$ TAGGED=${NEXUS_DOCKER_URL}/${BASE_IMAGE_NAME}:snapshot-MR${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID}
$ docker tag ${BASE_IMAGE_NAME}:latest ${TAGGED}
$ docker push ${TAGGED}
The push refers to repository [<custom-repository-url>/<image-name:tag>]
cade37b0f9c9: Preparing
578ec024f17c: Preparing
fe0b994190e8: Preparing
b24d08ca4359: Preparing
9a14db3b513b: Preparing
777b2c648970: Preparing
777b2c648970: Waiting
b24d08ca4359: Layer already exists
9a14db3b513b: Layer already exists
777b2c648970: Layer already exists
fe0b994190e8: Pushed
cade37b0f9c9: Pushed
578ec024f17c: Pushed
[DEPRECATION NOTICE] registry v2 schema1 support will be removed in an upcoming release. Please contact admins of the <custom-repository-url> registry NOW to avoid future disruption.
errors:
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I have tried debugging this behavior as well as search online for a solution but I have yet to find anything. It seems that for some reason, this specific Docker image cannot be uploaded. I have tried the same procedure from both a local machine as well as from stateless CI builders and the behavior is consistent i.e. I was able to push it only once and then the process kept failing.

For reference my `Dockerfile` is the following:

```
FROM <custom-repository-url>/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.10_9-alpine
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY build/libs/email-service.jar application.jar

# Set the appropriate timezone
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata && \
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime && \
    echo "America/New_York" > /etc/timezone

EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -jar ${OPTS} application.jar
```

Which is quite straightforward and does not hide anything complicated. I initially thought that the problem could have been attributed to using a proxied based image (i.e `FROM`) but this is done of several other projects without any issues.

I have tried also checking Nexus's logs and the only thing I see is the following:

```
2021-02-05 17:12:27,441+0000 ERROR [qtp1025847496-15765]  ci-deploy org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.orient.V2ManifestUtilImpl - Manifest refers to missing layer: sha256:66db482b5034f8eda0b18533d4eddb0012f4940bf3d348b08ac3bac8486bb2ee for: fts/marketing/email-service/snapshot-MR40 in repository RepositoryImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$4d5af99c{type=hosted, format=docker, name='docker-hosted-s3'}
2021-02-05 17:12:27,443+0000 ERROR [qtp1025847496-15765]  ci-deploy org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.orient.V2ManifestUtilImpl - Manifest refers to missing layer: sha256:2ec25ba939258edb2e85293896c5126478d79fe416d3b60feb20426755bcea5a for: fts/marketing/email-service/snapshot-MR40 in repository RepositoryImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$4d5af99c{type=hosted, format=docker, name='docker-hosted-s3'}
2021-02-05 17:12:27,445+0000 WARN  [qtp1025847496-15765]  ci-deploy org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers - Error: PUT /v2/fts/marketing/email-service/manifests/snapshot-MR40: 400 - org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Exception: Invalid Manifest
```

So my question are:

1. What does this error really mean? I don't find it very useful:

```
errors:
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
```

2. What is really causing this behavior and how can I address the problem?

Note (not that it should make any difference), the image is a dockerized Micronaut application, using the latest version of the framework.

For reference, the output of `docker inspect` for said image is the following:

```
[{
    "Id": "sha256:fec226a68e3b744fc792e47d3235e67f06b17883e60df52c8ae82c5a7ba9750f",
    "RepoTags": [
        "<custom-repository-url>/fts/marketing/email-service:mes-33-3",
        "test-mes-33:latest"
    ],
    "RepoDigests": [],
    "Parent": "sha256:ddd8e2235b60d7636283097fc61e5971c32b3006ee52105e2a77e7d4ee7e709e",
    "Comment": "",
    "Created": "2021-02-06T21:06:59.987108458Z",
    "Container": "8ab70692b75aac21d0866816aa52af5febf620744282d71a39dce55f81fe3e44",
    "ContainerConfig": {
        "Hostname": "8ab70692b75a",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8080/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
            "LANGUAGE=en_US:en",
            "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
            "JAVA_VERSION=jdk-11.0.10+9",
            "JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "#(nop) ",
            "CMD [\"/bin/sh\" \"-c\" \"java -jar ${OPTS} application.jar\"]"
        ],
        "Image": "sha256:ddd8e2235b60d7636283097fc61e5971c32b3006ee52105e2a77e7d4ee7e709e",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/home/app",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    },
    "DockerVersion": "19.03.13",
    "Author": "",
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8080/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
            "LANGUAGE=en_US:en",
            "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
            "JAVA_VERSION=jdk-11.0.10+9",
            "JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "java -jar ${OPTS} application.jar"
        ],
        "Image": "sha256:ddd8e2235b60d7636283097fc61e5971c32b3006ee52105e2a77e7d4ee7e709e",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/home/app",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": null
    },
    "Architecture": "amd64",
    "Os": "linux",
    "Size": 220998577,
    "VirtualSize": 220998577,
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/78561c2e477b099a547bead4ea17b677bb01376fc1ed1ce1cd942157d35c0329/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/af8ac4feace0cbecd616e2a02850ec366715aaa5ac8ad143cb633f52b0f6fbe2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/211a8e68c833f664de5d304838b8cd98b8e5e790f79da8b8839a4d52d02a8d66/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cbc98e7274ff8266425aed31989066ff7c5f7a46d9334b84110fc57d8b1d942c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c773dedbc53b81c2e68ad61811445c0377271db3af526dbf5a6aa6671d0b2b71/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/04240d9f745382480e52e04d8088de6f65a9ece0cd6e091953087f3d06fcc93c/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/04240d9f745382480e52e04d8088de6f65a9ece0cd6e091953087f3d06fcc93c/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/04240d9f745382480e52e04d8088de6f65a9ece0cd6e091953087f3d06fcc93c/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "RootFS": {
        "Type": "layers",
        "Layers": [
            "sha256:777b2c648970480f50f5b4d0af8f9a8ea798eea43dbcf40ce4a8c7118736bdcf",
            "sha256:9a14db3b513b928759670c6a9b15fd89a8ad9bf222c75e0998c21bcb04e25e48",
            "sha256:b24d08ca43598c9ea44f73c3f5dfca2b4897c475b2cc480bac98cccc42dce10f",
            "sha256:11d1fa1ad1ef523c60369c11b1096baf89c8d43afa53813e84c73d0926848598",
            "sha256:30001f69fd3b3b08fdbf6d843e38d0a16d0e46e84923f92480ac88603c0eb680",
            "sha256:b2d3c5f57d1d626a7501b8871f548fd7e1f7625fe05c1885c27ec415b14e9915"
        ]
    },
    "Metadata": {
        "LastTagTime": "2021-02-06T23:08:30.440032169+02:00"
    }
}]
```

Comment: I believe "Manifest refers to missing layer: sha256:66db482b5034f8eda0b18533d4eddb0012f4940bf3d348b08ac3bac8486bb2ee" may bespeak to database corruption.  My suggestion is to delete the manifest and try again.  Happy to make this an answer if desired, but I don't feel it answers either of your Qs insomuch as troubleshoots your issue.

Comment: After various tests we ended up cleaning the GitLab runners cache and the problem was resolved. Based on that I believe that there was indeed some corruption in the manifest database

Answer (score 0):

A docker registry (in your case Nexus) throws that error whenever it encounters a missing/invalid layer in the image.

Nexus used to have difficulty with foreign layers but that shouldn't be a problem since you are running quite a recent version.

I would think that you only need to enable "foreign layer caching" in Nexus to get this working.

It'd be helpful to include the output of `docker manifest inspect <custom-repository-url>/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.10_9-alpine` and `docker manifest inspect ${TAGGED}`

[Docker registry API spec](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/)

Comment: I have gone ahead and enabled `foreign layer caching` at NXRM as you suggested, and re-tried to push the image. Again even from the CI level or at my local dev machine, the process fails, so this seems not to address the issue. I have gone ahead and updated the original question with the output of `docker inspect`. Hope this helps.